# Make child divs expand and compress within parent

Tags: html, css

I have a top-bar of pages set up, and I would like to make the width of each "button" (`.contain`) expand or compress when a browser is made larger or smaller.

I saw a very good solution to this that used a float, but in my case this doesn't work, because adding this causes the buttons to stop showing up side-by-side; something I solved with an inline block.

I need a way to both keep the buttons side-by-side and make their widths adjust with a browser window. Any suggestions? My code is as follows:

```css
#topbar {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 38px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e2c4ff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.toppage {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.contain {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2c4ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div class="toppage">
    <div class="contain">hello</div>
    <div class="contain">goodbye</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <!---->
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
    <div class="contain">what are we doing?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you give `display: flex; justify-content: center;width: 100%;` to the `.toppage` , this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Container's contraction is useful as long as the content (text, in your case) inside it doesn't go out. You can use `Media Queries` to make responsive containers but the text inside will remain the same size. That is why when page size decreases, the container slips down, as text inside is of same **font-size**.

As I came up with, this problem can be solved in two ways:

> 1: Hard code CSS media queries to change **font-size**

This will require a lot of guess work and you'll have to use many `@media` rules to work it out. Use this only if you don't want to include `script` in your page.

> 2: Use JavaScript to handle **font-size**

This is the best solution I can think of. You can use JS(I use jQuery) to change font-size of text inside your `contain` div. Though this method also requires little hard coding. Here is the example code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
    <div class="contain">Button</div>
</div>
```

**Keep in mind:** When you change font-size of any text by 1px, all characters composing the text increases by 1px in size. Therefore:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var window_width = $(window).width();
        var contain_count = 10*6; // 10 contain elements * 6 characters of text 'button'
        var ratio = window_width/contain_count;
        $('.contain').css('font-size',ratio+'px')
    });
});
```

So if you wanna have buttons side-by-side no matter what, you also have to decrease their font-size.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position: absolute` for `.toppage`. For `.contain` use some width in percentage. It should work.

Comment: hmm... this works for expanding, but when the window is made smaller, the buttons move below each other, looking very glitchy. When compressing I would like the buttons to shrink only as far as they can while still keeping the buttons side-by-side, and the text on one line. Guess I should have been more clear on that. Any further help (from anyone who sees this) would be very useful. Code samples or previews would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In that case you can add min-width for that button. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I decided to settle on this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp . It doesn't do quite what I was thinking, but it looks very clean, and the code is neater than what I originally had.